# how to handle white spaces in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to write an SQL query that will fetch all the students who live in a specific Post Code. Following is my query.

```
SELECT * FROM `students` AS ss WHERE ss.`postcode` LIKE 'SE4 1NA';
```

Now the issue is that in database some records are saved without the white space is postcode, like `SE41NA` and some may also be in lowercase, like `se41na` or `se4 1na`.

The query gives me different results based on how the record is saved. Is there any way in which I can handle this?

Comment: Have you tried to use the **%** operator?

Comment: Look into using `replace`... I doubt the lowercase matters unless you have changed something manually.

Comment: @sgeddes It may (lowercase)  depending on mysql configuration.

Answer (score 3):

Using `regexp` is one way to do it. This performs a case insensitive match by default.

```
SELECT * FROM students AS ss 
WHERE ss.postcode REGEXP '^SE4[[:space:]]?1NA$';
```

`[[:space:]]?` matches an optional space character.

[REGEXP documentation MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html)

Answer (score 2):

Whether case matters depends on the collation of the string/column/database/server.  But, you can get around it by doing:

```
WHERE UPPER(ss.postcode) LIKE 'SE4%1NA'
```

The `%` will match any number of characters, including none.  It is a bit too general for what you might really need -- but it should work fine in practice.

The more important issue is that your database does not validate the data being put into it.  You should fix the application so the postal codes are correct and follow a standard format.

Answer (score 2):

Use a combination of `UPPER` and `REPLACE`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM students s 
WHERE UPPER(REPLACE(s.postcode, ' ', '')) LIKE '%SE41NA%'
```

Comment: if the white space is in in middle of text then above one will give wrong data

Comment: White space is replaced using the `REPLACE` function so no, it wouldn't.

Comment: first of all I am sorry . I am not notice that . but as per my opinion Upper and replace have less performance compare REGEXP

Comment: @KarthickRajan `REGEXP` is a lot slower in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM students AS ss 
  WHERE UPPER(REPLACE(ss.postcode, ' ', '')) = 'SE41NA' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM students AS ss 
 WHERE UPPER(ss.postcode) LIKE SELECT REPLACE(UPPER('SE4 1NA'), ' ', '%'); ;
```

I propose using the spaces replaced with the`'%'` placeholder. Also transform the case to upper for both sides of the `LIKE` operator